# tengo un sistema de usuarios con login y crud, cuando voy a entrar al crud este redirecciona nuevamente al login, que podría hacer?

Tags: php, html, mysql

este login registra e inicia sesion y luego llega una sesión

```html
<?php

    session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location/ sistema/index.php");
    exit;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bienvenidos -mmgalindo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="icon/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
    

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, 


        <div class="content-menu">

            
            <li><a href="index.php"><span class="lnr lnr-home icon1"></span><h4 class="text1">Inicio </h4></li>
            <li><a href="usuario.php"><span class="lnr lnr-film-play icon2"></span><h4 class="text2">Cursos</h4></li>
            <li><a href="sistema"><span class="lnr lnr-store icon3"></span><h4 class="text3">sistema</h4></li>
            <li><a href="usuario.php"><span class="lnr lnr-picture icon4"></span><h4 class="text4">usuario</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-briefcase icon5"></span><h4 class="text5">Foro</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-license icon6"></span><h4 class="text6">Blog</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-bubble icon7"></span><h4 class="text7">Mensajes</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-envelope icon8"></span><h4 class="text8">Contactos</h4></li>
            <li><span class="lnr lnr-question-circle icon9"></span><h4 class="text9">Nosotros</h4></li>
            
        </div>
```

de bienvenida donde puede entrar al crud, ya probe con la validaciones y algunas veces funciona y otras no, tambien probe xdebug por si era prole del servidor y no pude solucionar el problema el crud se encuentra en carpeta llamada sistema.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para iniciar sesión, probablemente algo falta ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar la sesion esto te puede servir:
Lo puedes utilizar como quieras aunque tu error es basicamente este:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location/ sistema/index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Si te fijas se lee asi, si no exite la variable de sesion loggedin o no es verdadero redireciona al sistema index.php solo que colocas un espacio de más si ese no es el error entonces así que el problema radica probablemente en la redireccion te lo dejare al final es una funcion que utilizo yo para casos en los hosting normalmente el problema esta ahi a la hora de redirigir.
Por otra parte no entiendo porque lo haces con el condicional OR es decir que con solo cumplirse una de ellas te redireccionara al index tal vez deberias probar con AND =  &&.
Aquí esta el codigo para sesion una funcion que se explica sola:

```
public static function sesion_iniciada()
    {
    if (version_compare(phpversion(), "5.4.0") != -1) {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
    } else {
        if (session_id() == '') {
            session_start();
        }
    }


    if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        return true;
    } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
 }
```

Funcion para redirigir :

```
public static function redirigir($url)
    {
        if (!headers_sent()) {
            # echo "Funciona el if";
            # header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);
            exit();
        } else {
            #echo "<h1>ElseElseElseElse</h1><br> ";
            #echo "<h1>ElseElseElseElse</h1><br> ";
            #echo "<h1>ElseElseElseElse</h1><br> ";
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'window.location.href="' . $url . '";';
            echo '</script>';
            echo '<noscript>';
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=' . $url . '" />';
            echo '</noscript>';
        }
    }
```